# Evaluate table from row x to row y

Tags: dax, ssas

I am trying to extract a table to a flat file using python and the `ssas_api` package, allowing me to run DAX queries from python code.
The table is fairly big and because of that a simple `EVALUATE tablename` query will timeout after 1h.
I want to split the queries into smaller ones, iterating over the table by chunks of let say 20k lines for example.
I could do the first chunk using `TOPN` but what about the next ones?

Comment: Use function TOPNSKIP

Comment: Cheers, do you know if the function is supporting on the fly table? I am getting the "not supported parameter combination" error when trying to apply it on a custom table built with `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`

Comment: It only works with physical tables: https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/topnskip-dax-guide/
A possible workaround is here: https://dax.tips/2019/05/14/topnskip-alternative/

Comment: Yeah I had seen the workaround but it requires to know the data as it selects using data value instead of index i.e. row number. Thanks anyway